# Unable to set breakpoints using jdb and sbt

Tags: scala, debugging, sbt, jdb

I am having trouble getting my breakpoints to hit in jdb when attaching to sbt. I wrote the following scala code, and put it in a file called test.scala:

```
object test extends App {
  def foo(x: Int): Int = {
    print(".")
    Thread.sleep(100)
    x
  }  

  println("started")
  List.range(1, 100).foreach { a =>
    foo(a)
  } 
  println("done")
}
```

Then, in the dir containing test.scala, I start sbt and run the program once to make sure everything is working ok.

```
sbt -jvm-debug 5005
> run
```

In another terminal (same dir), I start jdb:

```
jdb -attach 5005
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Initializing jdb ...
> stop in test.foo
Set breakpoint test.foo
> stop in test$.foo
Set breakpoint test$.foo
> stop at test.scala:3
Deferring breakpoint test.scala:3.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
```

Then type 'run' in sbt, and the program completes without stopping. However, jdb seems to know enough about the code to be able to set a breakpoint. When I run again, but interrupt all threads in jdb with 'suspend' I can look at the output of 'threads':

```
jdb> threads
Group system:
  (java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler)0x1627 Reference Handler cond. waiting
  (java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread)0x1626  Finalizer         cond. waiting
  (java.lang.Thread)0x1625                         Signal Dispatcher running
Group main:
  (java.lang.Thread)0x1628                         main              cond. waiting
  (java.lang.Thread)0x162a                         pool-4-thread-1   cond. waiting
  (java.lang.Thread)0x162b                         pool-4-thread-2   cond. waiting
  (java.lang.Thread)0x162c                         pool-4-thread-3   cond. waiting
  (java.lang.Thread)0x162d                         pool-4-thread-4   cond. waiting
  (java.lang.Thread)0x162e                         pool-4-thread-5   cond. waiting
  (java.lang.Thread)0x162f                         pool-4-thread-6   cond. waiting
Group run-main-group-2:
  (java.lang.Thread)0x1630                         run-main-2        sleeping
```

Select the thread running the test:

```
jdb> thread 0x1630
run-main-2[1] where
[1] java.lang.Thread.sleep (native method)
[2] test$.foo (test.scala:4)
...

run-main-2[1] step up
> 
Step completed: "thread=run-main-2", test$.foo(), line=5 bci=14
run-main-2[1] class test
Class: test
extends: java.lang.Object
nested: test$
...

run-main-2[1] methods test
** methods list **
test main(java.lang.String[])
test delayedInit(scala.Function0)
test args()
test scala$App$_setter_$executionStart_$eq(long)
test executionStart()
test foo(int)
```

So, jdb appears to know about the class and method names as well as the line numbers in my code, but does not stop at the breakpoints. If I set a breakpoint on a function that doesn't exist, I get:

```
> stop in test.whatever
Unable to set breakpoint test.whatever : No method whatever in test
```

Indicating that it does understand a breakpoint at test.foo ? It does not matter whether I use stop in, on or at for test.foo or test$.foo. From googling other questions it seems most likely that I have the method name wrong, but I wouldn't know what it would have to be then.

I was hoping to be able to add some simple debugging to my existing development setup without having to switch to Eclipse or IntelliJ. Is there something I am doing wrong or not at all, or is there no easy way to make this work?

Version information:

- Linux: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (precise)
- jdb: 1.6 (Java SE version 1.6.0_31)
- sbt: 0.13.5
- scala: 2.10.4
- java version "1.6.0_31"

  - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
  - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I just found that `stop at test$:3` does get hit.